# Sort by the sum of array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am looking for a solution to sort an array by the sum of an array property within an object.

For example if the main array is

```
[
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          11,
          12
       ]
     },
     "Name": "One"
  },
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          5,
          2
       ]
     },
     "Name": "Two"
   }
]
```

How can I sort the sum of `Day` to return as

```
[
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          5,
          2
       ]
     },
     "Name": "Two"
  },
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          11,
          12
       ]
     },
     "Name": "One"
   }
]
```

Comment: If it's not a string it ain't no [JSON](http://json.org). That's just an array of objects.

Comment: True, in the example it is. My actual case scenario is slightly more complex and is `JSON`. I just referenced to find true solution to my troubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your array with comparator, that uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to calc sum of inner array values:

```js
let arr = [{"Grid": {"Day": [11,12]}, "Name": "One"},
           {"Grid": {"Day": [5,2]}, "Name": "Two"},
           {"Grid": {"Day": [1,2]}, "Name": "Two"}];
           
let sum = el => el.Grid.Day.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
arr.sort((a,b) => sum(a) - sum(b));

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @Darren _"worked best"_ - All answers use the exact same approach with `reduce`...

Comment: Yes @Andreas, yet this method worked best for my case. The others I tried did not handle negative sums in the way I wanted. This one did.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `reduce` to sum the array, and `sort` to order the output:

```js
var input = [
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          11,
          12
       ]
     },
     "Name": "One"
  },
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          5,
          2
       ]
     },
     "Name": "Two"
   }
];


var result = input.sort( (a,b) =>  sumOfDay(a) - sumOfDay(b));
console.log(result);

function sumOfDay(obj){
    return obj.Grid.Day.reduce( (acc,curr) => acc + curr, 0);
}
```

Note that [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) actually mutates the original array in place. so the above could also do

```
input.sort( (a,b) =>  sumOfDay(a) - sumOfDay(b));
console.log(input);
```

So, don't fall into the trap of thinking the original array is unchanged just because I  assigned the result to `result`!.

If you do wish to sort a *copy* of the array do this:

```
var result = input.slice().sort( (a,b) =>  sumOfDay(a) - sumOfDay(b));
```

Comment: `var result = input.sort( (a,b) =>  sumOfDay(a) - sumOfDay(b));` this is redundant, since `result === input` - they are literally the same object.

Comment: @VLAZ although you're right the docs actually say "The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place **and returns the sorted array**". I prefer to use the returned value for clarity (and the fact I hate that it mutates the original)

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong - I hate that it mutates it, too. However, seeing this code implies that the original is *not* mutated. This tends to be more problematic than the actual mutation, if people don't realise it. You can do an `input.slice()` to clone the array, though.

Comment: @VLAZ very true. I'll  add some clarity to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Array of `a` by mapping through it and using `reduce` on the `Day` Array of `Grid` to get your sum which you can compare within a `sort` to return your list sorted by summed days.

```js
const a = [
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          11,
          12
       ]
     },
     "Name": "One"
  },
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          5,
          2
       ]
     },
     "Name": "Two"
   }
]

const daySum = ({Grid}) => Grid.Day.reduce((prev, curr) => prev+curr, 0)

const sorted = [...a].sort(daySum)

console.log(sorted)
console.log(a) //Original array intact
```

Comment: `const sorted = a.sort((gA, gB) => getSum(gA) > getSum(gB))` this is redundant, since `sorted === a` - they are literally the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Just "another" approach to solve the issue: assuming you (someday, later, eventually) may need to sort again, a good approach may also be to add a property to each grid item holding the sum of the days, avoiding the .reduce call every time you need to sort the array.

In this approach, `.forEach` is used to create the new property (through `.reduce`), and then `.sort` is used to sort the array in-place.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          11,
          12
       ]
     },
     "Name": "One"
  },
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          5,
          2
       ]
     },
     "Name": "Two"
   }
];
// Add a DaySum property evaluating the sum of the days.
input.forEach(i => i.Grid.DaySum = i.Grid.Day.reduce((a,b) => a + b));
//                                                                 ^--- the second parameter (initial value) is unneeded here due to the fact that all elements are actually numeric, hence if the initial value is the first element of the array, which is a number already.
// Sor the array by that property.
input.sort((a,b) => a.Grid.DaySum - b.Grid.DaySum);
console.log(input);
```

Or, as suggested by @Andreas below, you can directly assign the property while sorting:

```js
const input = [
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          11,
          12
       ]
     },
     "Name": "One"
  },
  {
    "Grid": {
       "Day": [
          5,
          2
       ]
     },
     "Name": "Two"
   }
];

const sum = (a,b) => a + b;
input.sort((a,b) => {
  a.Grid.DaySum = a.Grid.DaySum || a.Grid.Day.reduce(sum);
  b.Grid.DaySum = b.Grid.DaySum || b.Grid.Day.reduce(sum);
  return a.Grid.DaySum - b.Grid.DaySum;
});
console.log(input);
```

Comment: Did you mean the *second* parameter is unneeded? Also its not because they are all numeric - its unneeded because `reduce` without a seed gets the first array element as the first accumulator.

Comment: @Jamiec yup, second parameter, not third. Also, added about undefined + number. Not sure whether it was necessary, but still.

Comment: `.forEach()` is unnecessary "overhead". Add the property in `.sort()` (check if it is available. If not -> ...)

Comment: @Andreas That would be clever, indeed. Won't it be less performant for huge loops though? I mean, checking **every** time whether the element has that property... Right? Wouldn't it be more efficient to create the property once and be sure to have it available for the next iterations?

Comment: For an array of length `n` this would cause `n` function calls (context change, copy values, garbage collection) vs. `2 x <number of sort rounds>` comparisons for `undefined`. I haven't tested it, but I would guess the comparison may be slightly _"better"_

Comment: @Andreas I've added the sort implementation as well, not sure what would be the fastest, but still, it's there. Thanks for raising that :)